# Magento CE 1.9 ordering ccs files

Tags: theme, ce-1.9.0.1

I'm running CE 1.9.0 & I've created a sub theme of the rwd template.

So I have folders like so:
app/design/frontend/rwd/mytheme/layout/local.xml
app/design/frontend/rwd/mytheme/templates/ - currently empty

skin/frontend/rwd/mytheme/css/custom.css

In local.xml I have the following directive:

```
 <default>

    <reference name="head">

         <action method="addItem">
              <type>skin_css</type>
              <name>css/custom.css</name>
          </action>

      </reference>
    </default>
```

However, the custom.css is being output at the top - even before the various js files, so that the rwd theme css is overriding my changes.

Within the Admin UI I have the following Design settings[image: Design Settings]

Anyone know why my custom.css is being output first, rather than last as I'd expect?

Thanks,
Eddie

Answer (score 12):

### Cause of problem

The `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head::getCssJsHtml` method is responsible for outputting the CSS/JS files that are added by the `addItem` method. The method groups items by their "if" condition, which results in any items with "if" values being grouped after those without "if":

```
switch ($item['type']) {
    case 'js':        // js/*.js
    case 'skin_js':   // skin/*/*.js
    case 'js_css':    // js/*.css
    case 'skin_css':  // skin/*/*.css
        $lines[$if][$item['type']][$params][$item['name']] = $item['name'];
        break;
    default:
        $this->_separateOtherHtmlHeadElements($lines, $if, $item['type'], $params, $item['name'], $item);
        break;
}
```

The `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml` file adds the CSS files using conditional IE-style comments:

```
<!-- Add stylesheets with no media queries for use in IE 8 and below -->
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles-ie8.css</name><params/><if><![CDATA[ (lte IE 8) & (!IEMobile)]]></if></action>
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/madisonisland-ie8.css</name><params/><if><![CDATA[ (lte IE 8) & (!IEMobile)]]></if></action>

<!-- Add stylesheets with media queries for use by modern browsers -->
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles.css</name><params/></action>
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/madisonisland.css</name><params/><if><![CDATA[<!--[if (gte IE 9) | (IEMobile)]><!-->]]></if></action>
```

### Solution

If you want to be able to add multiple CSS/JS files after the native files using the standard addItem/addJs methods, you can follow these steps:

1. Create this file `app/design/frontend/custompackage/customtheme/layout/local.xml` and add these contents:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <layout version="0.1.0">
       <default translate="label" module="page">
           <reference name="head">
               <block type="page/html_head" name="head_custom" template="page/html/head_custom.phtml">
               <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/custom.css</name></action>
               </block>
           </reference>
       </default>
   </layout>
   ```

You're creating a new `head_custom` block so that you can add new items to it. If you look at the `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/head.phtml` file, you will see that `getChildHtml()` is being called after `getCssJsHtml()`, so `head.phtml` will first load all of the native CSS/JS files, and will then load the `head_custom` block, which will in turn load your custom CSS/JS files.

2. Create this file `app/design/frontend/custompackage/customtheme/template/page/html/head_custom.phtml` and add this content to that file:

   ```
   <?php echo $this->getCssJsHtml(); ?>
   ```

Now, any items you add to the `head_custom` block will load beneath the native CSS/JS items.

Comment: Hi Erik, thanks for your detailed response &sorry for the delay in responding. I'll try this later & report on progress.

Comment: Is the custom phtml template necessary? At first glance it seems to be working for me without it.

Comment: Thanks Erik. Been breaking my head on this for a while. Worked perfectly!

Comment: @Erik And what if "Merge CSS Files" is enabled? Will this additional custom.css be merged with other CSS files?

Comment: @zitix - Yes, the custom.css file will be merged with other CSS files if "Merge CSS Files" is enabled.

Answer (score 5):

What about just to add into local.xml same css like that:

```
<reference name="head">
    <!-- Add stylesheets with no media queries for use in IE 8 and below -->
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/custom.css</name><params/><if><![CDATA[ (lte IE 8) & (!IEMobile)]]></if></action>
    <!-- Add stylesheets with media queries for use by modern browsers -->
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/custom.css</name><params/><if><![CDATA[<!--[if (gte IE 9) | (IEMobile)]><!-->]]></if></action>
</reference>
```

And nothing more! :-)

Comment: Nice. This is the simpliest solution I know :)