# How do I set a stylesheet to be last?

Tags: layout, css

I'm trying to add a stylesheet to the very bottom of the loaded stylesheets, and am having a hard time figuring out the best way to do it.

I tried using this extentension:

https://github.com/drewhunter/ItemPosition/blob/master/modman

Which seems like it should work, but doesn't quite do it. If I add the 'setLastItem' method to the bottom of my page.xml head block, any css from other modules is added after the 'last' item set.

It would be great to have a weight associated with a stylesheet - so you could declare something like this in the layout:

```
<action method="addCss">
  <stylesheet>put_me_at_the_end.css</stylesheet>
  <weight>1000</weight>
</action>
```

But even then, you'd still need all of the css to be aggregated through all the extensions and then weighted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume that you're using the latest version of Magento (CE 1.9 / EE 1.14). If so, you'll want to reference this answer, as it should resolve your issue: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/20942/2142

Comment: Thanks Erik - the above solution works for my purposes, although I still think having a weighted system for css & js rather than an extra block would be a cleaner solution.  I added the extra block to the page.xml layout file, and called the childGetHtml('head_custom') from the head.phtml file.

Comment: Noting here that users should be careful with the call to getCssJsHtml() in the head_custom.phtml file in the link above - I had a 3rd party module overloading that method with it's own constructor, and ended up adding more than the expected files to the page.